# Fastest and most effiecient way to find out non-transparent pixel of UIImage on iOS

Tags: ios, image-processing, opengl-es, alpha-transparency

I want to ask about image processing mechanism. I develop an iOS app which using OpenGLES for hand-writing on a view. I have a function save that convert a view with all drawing to an Image and save to Photo Library.

I can properly convert content of view to image easily using below code
(Note: The following code is not the problem. Its purpose is just to convert content of view to image and it worked perfect, but I show here for reference)

```
// Get the size of the backing CAEAGLLayer

    NSInteger x = 0, y = 0, width = backingWidth, height = backingHeight;
    NSInteger dataLength = width * height * 4;
    GLubyte *data = (GLubyte*)malloc(dataLength * sizeof(GLubyte));

    // Read pixel data from the framebuffer
    glPixelStorei(GL_PACK_ALIGNMENT, 4);
    glReadPixels(x, y, width, height, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, data);

    // Create a CGImage with the pixel data
    // If your OpenGL ES content is opaque, use kCGImageAlphaNoneSkipLast to ignore the alpha channel
    // otherwise, use kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast
    CGDataProviderRef ref = CGDataProviderCreateWithData(NULL, data, dataLength, NULL);
    CGColorSpaceRef colorspace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
    CGImageRef iref = CGImageCreate(width, height, 8, 32, width * 4, colorspace, kCGBitmapByteOrder32Big | kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast,
                                    ref, NULL, true, kCGRenderingIntentDefault);

    // OpenGL ES measures data in PIXELS
    // Create a graphics context with the target size measured in POINTS
    NSInteger widthInPoints, heightInPoints;
    if (NULL != &UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions) {
        // On iOS 4 and later, use UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions to take the scale into consideration
        // Set the scale parameter to your OpenGL ES view's contentScaleFactor
        // so that you get a high-resolution snapshot when its value is greater than 1.0
        CGFloat scale = self.contentScaleFactor;
        widthInPoints = width / scale;
        heightInPoints = height / scale;
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(CGSizeMake(widthInPoints, heightInPoints), NO, scale);
    } else {
        // On iOS prior to 4, fall back to use UIGraphicsBeginImageContext

    }

    CGContextRef cgcontext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    // UIKit coordinate system is upside down to GL/Quartz coordinate system
    // Flip the CGImage by rendering it to the flipped bitmap context
    // The size of the destination area is measured in POINTS
    CGContextSetBlendMode(cgcontext, kCGBlendModeCopy);
    CGContextDrawImage(cgcontext, CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, widthInPoints, heightInPoints), iref);

    // Retrieve the UIImage from the current context
    UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    // Clean up
    free(data);
    CFRelease(ref);
    CFRelease(colorspace);
    CGImageRelease(iref);

    return image;
```

The problem is I want to determine if the view has any drawing or not. If no drawing -> can't save because saving a blank image is useless so my thinking is to check if image has any non-transparent pixel or not

My solution

- Convert my drawing view to Image (its pixels have alpha channel)
- Check if the Image has any non-zero alpha channel pixel

  - If yes, user properly draws something -> can Save
  - If no, user not draws anything or user erases everything -> not Save

I know the BruteForce algorithim to go through all pixels but it seems the worst way and just be implemented if there is no other efficient ways

So is there any efficient way to check it

Comment: A better approach might be to store the handwriting layer as grayscale+alpha. That would be 8 bits of greyscale and 8 bits of alpha channel which would be 1/2 the total amount of data to scan through if speed is critical. Memory access for very large bitmaps is typically the choke point. Your code can maintain this handwriting buffer and composite it over the background at runtime. Scanning would then be a matter of looking for non-zero values which is fast. You might also render the 16 bit values and generate an 8bit table of "used values" that combine the 8 bit gray and alpha as a byte.

Answer (score 0):

I found that the BruteForce algorithm is not slower as I though. It just take about less than 200 miliseconds to go through all pixel datas of an image has size of iPad Pro as well as iPad mini 2

So I though using BruteForce is acceptable

Following is code to check

```
    CGImageRef imageRef = [selfImage CGImage];
    NSUInteger width = CGImageGetWidth(imageRef);
    NSUInteger height = CGImageGetHeight(imageRef);

    float total = width * height * 4;

    CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
    unsigned char *rawData = (unsigned char*) calloc(total, sizeof(unsigned char));
    NSUInteger bytesPerPixel = 4;
    NSUInteger bytesPerRow = bytesPerPixel * width;
    NSUInteger bitsPerComponent = 8;
    CGContextRef tempContext = CGBitmapContextCreate(rawData, width, height,
                                                     bitsPerComponent, bytesPerRow, colorSpace,
                                                     kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast | kCGBitmapByteOrder32Big);
    CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);

    CGContextDrawImage(tempContext, CGRectMake(0, 0, width, height), imageRef);
    CGContextRelease(tempContext);

    // Now your rawData contains the image data in the RGBA8888 pixel format
    BOOL empty = YES;
    for (int i = 0 ; i < total ;) {
        CGFloat alpha = ((CGFloat) rawData[i + 3] ) / 255.0f;
        //        CGFloat red   = ((CGFloat) rawData[i]     ) / alpha;
        //        CGFloat green = ((CGFloat) rawData[i + 1] ) / alpha;
        //        CGFloat blue  = ((CGFloat) rawData[i + 2] ) / alpha;
        i += bytesPerPixel;

        if (alpha != 0) {
            empty = NO;
            break;
        }
    }

    if (empty) {
        //Do something
    } else {
        //Do other thing
    }
```

If is there any improvement or other effiecient algorithms, please post here, I really appreciate